Relation between discontinuity and imaginary part of a function
I have a question regarding a relation that's often encountered in scattering physics, for which I'd like to know why and to what extent it is true.
Given a complex-valued function $f(s)$ of a complex variable $s$, we define the discontinuity of $f$ by:
\begin{equation}
\forall s \in \mathbb{R}, \: \text{Disc}_s f(s) = \lim\limits_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \frac{1}{2i} (f(s+i\varepsilon)-f(s-i\varepsilon))
\end{equation}
It is then said that:
\begin{equation}
\text{Disc}_s f(s) = \text{Im} f(s)
\end{equation}
This relation being widely used e.g. in partial wave expansions.
I'd like to know, as stated above, to what extent this relation is true (i.e., what are the assumptions one must make on $f$ for it to hold) and why (i.e., how does one prove it). Thanks !
Remarks:

This question might be a bit sloppy by its very nature ("can you tell me how to make this statement true and then tell me why it is true ?"), but I don't have enough knowledge to phrase it better.
Someone already posted something in the lines of my question here, but said question was never answered.


If $f$ is continuous at $s$, then $\text{Disc}_s f(s) = 0$.  That is all I can see.  Now, from the link, I am guessing that the real line is a branch cut for $f$, so the value "f(s)" is not defined?

An example
Let $f(z) = \sqrt{z}$ with branch cut along the negative real axis.  Let's take $s=-2$ on the branch cut.  So for $\varepsilon \to 0, \varepsilon > 0$,
\begin{align}
\sqrt{-2+i\varepsilon} &= i\sqrt{2} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\varepsilon+O(\varepsilon^2)
\\
\sqrt{-2-i\varepsilon} &= -i\sqrt{2} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\varepsilon+O(\varepsilon^2)
\\
\sqrt{-2+i\varepsilon}-\sqrt{-2-i\varepsilon} &= i2\sqrt{2}+O(\varepsilon^2)
\\
\frac{1}{2i}\big(\sqrt{-2+i\varepsilon}-\sqrt{-2-i\varepsilon}\big) &= \sqrt{2}+O(\varepsilon^2)
\\
\lim_{\epsilon \searrow 0}\frac{1}{2i}\big(\sqrt{-2+i\varepsilon}-\sqrt{-2-i\varepsilon}\big) &= \sqrt{2}
\end{align}
Now, the imaginary part of $\sqrt{-2}$ could be either $\sqrt{2}$ or $-\sqrt{2}$, depending on what we do on the branch cut itself.

Yes, it's true that actually $\text{Im} : f(s)$ isn't even well-defined per se, and one should specify what's meant by this quantity. I'll investigate it further for the general case and post my findings here (if I find something...). Thanks for this example !
